# Search functionality, performance - SQL

Tags: sql, database, search

I was thinking how search functionality is done in big sites like stackoverflow. For instance the most straight-forward idea for implementing search by some phrase is:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someColumn LIKE '%somePhrase%'
```

however above query doesn't scale well (database can't even use index for that). Besides performance issues suppose I'd like to implement more sophisticated algorithm (ex. using edit distance, levenshtein algorithm) - how could it be implemented?

Comment: Look up "full text searching".

Comment: Don't just limit yourself to database in terms of mysql/oracle. Have a look at Lucene/Nutch/Solr etc.

Comment: @SMA thanks, didn't even heard about that before